# Useful code completion with dictionaries vs. classes

Tags: python, class, dictionary, pycharm, code-completion

In Python, it is convenient to represent structured, hierarchical data as dictionaries (or dictionaries of dictionaries of dictionaries...). Then you end up with code like:

```
myDict["myField"]["mySubFieldofField"] = someValue
```

But the alternative is to use classes:

```
myObject.myField.mySubFieldofField = someValue
```

The nice thing about classes is that PyCharm (and presumably other IDEs) can tell you at any given time what fields the object should have and what, exactly, they are called. Whereas with dictionaries, there is always going back and forth to check if the field is called `some_field` or `some-field` or `some field` or `SomeField` which can get to be a real pain in the neck.

Classes, unfortunately, are more hassle to create than dictionaries.

Is there any way to have an IDE suggest to you what existing dictionary keys are available, and how they are spelled, in situations like this?

Comment: Classes are actually pretty easy.  Just use [`collections.namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#namedtuple-factory-function-for-tuples-with-named-fields) instead of writing them out by hand.